# Universal Windows app with Web API

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

This question may broad to answer. But just give me idea/structure.
I'm planning to build a shopping cart app for Windows Store. My logic behind the app is

1. Developing Web API and hosting on server
2. Accessing those API through app and displaying data on XAML UI

Is that right? or any other logic that i need to follow?

Should i use MVVM?

Answer (score 0):

Though it might be a little harder at first, using MVVM is always a good idea.

As for your logic, why do you need Web APIs for your cart app ?
Wouldn't it be more efficient to keep everything local ?

Comment: Everything local? How can? Price/items are dynamic one

Comment: Oh, I thought it was a cart like a grocery list.
You need to tell a little bit more on your project basis if you want to have more precise insights.